# What is the most accepted architecture for building a page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, architecture

This may be a pretty simple question but I want to see what is out there...

On our site, we currently have top level .html files that make up the base of the page. Within the .html pages, we are using

```
<?php include_once('php/...'); ?>
```

's all over the place to pull in php, js, and css files.

In general we try to keep all of the languages in their own files and use the html file as a platform for them to interact and create the page. For example, when we are using php to determine content dynamically, it is typed on the .html file. Otherwise, we keep all php functions and php interactions with mysql on a separate file php.

Our folder structure looks somewhat like this:

/site/
/site/php/
/site/js/
/site/css/
...

---

How do you keep you code clean? What is the convention for professional developers?